# How to upgrade to the latest version of OpenSSL on Windows 7?

Tags: tomcat, openssl

Can anybody help me on how to upgrade to the latest version of OpenSSL on windows 7? Currently my OpenSSL version is 0.9.8g and also I am using Tomcat 6. Does Tomcat 6 supports OpenSSL 1.0.1h or do I need to upgrade to Tomcat 7?

And also please suggest me any tool for testing the install version of OpenSSL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Download The Tomcat Native Connector 1.1.31 Windows binaries from the ASF (http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi) . That bundle is built using OpenSSL 1.0.1h and includes a Windows OpenSSL binary as well as the native component of the APR/native connector. It works will all currently supported versions of Tomcat (6, 7 & 8)